# What are the differences between Android ICS and Jelly Bean?

Tags: java, android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I'm curious about the differences between Jelly Bean and ICS (Ice Cream Sandwich). Is there anything special I need to do while developing for either of the OS?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html

Comment: I'm more interested in the technical differences and what I need to change when developing. Not so much the features that the end user will experience.

Comment: Not much I suspect, especially if you want to support older versions too.

Comment: @BlaineOmega This question will very likely be closed. Consider making future questions more refined, e.g. focus on breaking changes in API or other more technical details, hopefully for an *existing* codebase being developed ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't appear to be anything special that you need to do going from one to the other. Jelly Bean just has some framework updates, etc.

**RESOURCES**

- http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.1.html

Answer (score 0):

With each release you can find highlights listed on developer.android.com, so you can find out what in general changed, so you at least can check if your areas of interest are affected or not. For more detailed changelog i suspect you should lurk into code repo, however at first you may want to look here: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look @ here :

http://www.androidauthority.com/android-4-0-ice-cream-sandwich-vs-android-4-1-jelly-bean-comparison-video-105805/

http://blogs.computerworld.com/mobile-and-wireless/20661/android-41-jelly-bean

Hope you will get the difference between Android ICS and Jelly Bean. It is well & precise defined.